# Problem with append to dict in Python multiprocessing code

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have problem with multiprocessing code below, after running it in Jupyter notebook program freeze and kernel restarting is requited. `Data` variable contains 60x2001 DataFrame, some of this data is extracted to `dict_results` as key of dictionary and variable `score` as value.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def search_regression_loop(data, row, dict_results):
    for row2 in range(2000):
        if row != row2:
            score = linear_model_pred_iloc(data.iloc[:,:51], row, row2)
            if (score > 0.30) and (score != 1):
                if (data.iloc[row,54] is not None) and (data.iloc[row2,54] is not None):
                    name =str(data.iloc[row,54]) + ' - ' + str(data.iloc[row2,54])
                    dict_results[name] = score                
                else:
                    name = str(data.iloc[row].name) + ' - ' + str(data.iloc[row2].name)
                    dict_results[name] = score

manager = mp.Manager()
dict_results = manager.dict()
procs = []

for row in tqdm(range(2000)):
    p = mp.Process(target=search_regression_loop, args=(tumor,row,dict_results))
    procs.append(p)
    p.start()

for p in procs:
    p.join()
```

Comment: well, for starters, you are creating *2000* processes.

Comment: In any case, are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: As an aside, this is almost certainly the wrong approach altogether. It would be best if you described in words what you were trying to do

Comment: I'm working on Windows. Im trying use function linear_model_pred_iloc that return score from linear regression from sklearn library. Next if score is bigger than 30% pass name of this rows as key and score as value.

Comment: processes don't share data and it has to write `DataFrame` to file (in `pickle` format) and process has to read it. Maybe it would be faster to read file directly in process. Besides running 2000 processes at the same time doesn't have to run faster - because all processes want to use CPU at the same time - sometimes it can be better to use `Multiprocessing.Pool` to run only 4-8 processes at the same time. Some tutorials/documentations suggetst to use 4 processes at the same time if you have 4 CPUs (4 Cores)

Comment: this code will calculate values for the same pairs of rows `(A,B)` and `(B,A)` - if order doesn't matter then you could reduce it using `for row2 in range(row+1, 2000)`